# Gradle Daemon Android Studio: "Unable to start the daemon process"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, daemon

I am having a problem. I have always developed applications in Android Studio and never had a problems, but now I had the following error:

> Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by
>   incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an unrecognized
>   jvm option is used.
>
> Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at
>   https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

I already changed in `gradle.properties` the following line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

to

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

I also delete the folder `.gradle` in Users.

Comment: Have you tried updating to a different version of Gradle? 4.9 is the latest. What operating system are you using? What happens if you try to run a build from CLI instead of AS?

Comment: I did not change the gradle version, How can I change? I'm using Windows  8.1, I dont know who is this?? " run a build from CLI instead of AS", Thanks

Comment: Navigate to gradle-wrapper.properties and change the version number to 4.9. AS = Android Studio and CLI = command line interface.

Comment: I already changed the version to 4.9 but it didn't work, Thanks

Comment: DId you get through this error? I am also getting the same and do all possible things but nothing worked!!

Comment: I could not solve the problem, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Check your local firewall. I found an update of the firewall in my AV software to cause the same error. When I disable the firewall, the demon start succeeds.

I had the same problem on 3 different PCs. I disabled the firewall and everything worked just fine. Even if my IDE is not blocked by the firewall.

I am using BullGuard's firewall on Windows 10 Home. Maybe there is a better way to solve this problem, because I actually don't want to disable the firewall everytime I start programming with gradle and java.

At least this worked just fine for the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Check your local firewall. I found an update of the firewall in my AV software to cause the same error. When I disable the firewall, the demon start succeeds.

Answer (score -1):

just disable antivirus then try again ;)